# custom validity at least one checkbox is selected jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two checkboxes for gender . male and female. how will i set my validation for at least one gender should be selected. I also have 1 week set of days, from monday to sunday. it is also at least one selection of days. here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            // --- set required message --- //

                var msg="";
                var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

                for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                   elements[i].oninvalid =function(e) {
                        if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                        switch(e.target.name){                              
                            case 'gender' :
                                e.target.setCustomValidity("Please select at least one gender.");break;                             
                            case 'days' :
                                e.target.setCustomValidity("Please select at least one day.");break;
                            case 'location' :
                                e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a location where the image can be seen.");break;
                        default : e.target.setCustomValidity("");break;

                        }
                       }
                    };
                   elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
                        e.target.setCustomValidity(msg);
                    };
                }
            });



<input type=checkbox name=gender[] required>Male
<input type=checkbox name=gender[] required>Female

<input type=checkbox name=days[] required>Monday
<input type=checkbox name=days[] required>Tuesday
<input type=checkbox name=days[] required>Wednesday
<input type=checkbox name=days[] required>Thursday
<input type=checkbox name=days[] required>Friday
<input type=checkbox name=days[] required>Saturday
<input type=checkbox name=days[] required>Sunday
```

Comment: wouldn't gender be a radio group more likely, although now adays who knows.. ;]

Comment: @webkit yes i know. but on my web. there is a selection where male can only be seen and female. or can be both. so i made a checkbox so that it can be optionally both genders. same with the days on which day can be viewed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the html5 required and validity.. You can just use jquery to see if a checkbox is checked..

```
if($("input[name='gender[]']").is(":checked").length < 1){
 // no gender selected..
 var errmsg = $("<div class='error'>Please select at least one gender</div>");

}
if($("input[name='days[]']").is(":checked").length < 1){
 // no day selected..
 var errmsg = $("<div class='error'>Please select at least one day</div>");
}

$("containerelement").append(errmsg);
```

Comment: can i still set the message like from the html5 for this?

Comment: @Vincent I've updated the answer above with a template example of how you would use an error message.. just decide where to insert it, style it with css, and don't forget to remove it when checking validity again.. should be in a function, let me know if you need help with it.

Comment: can't i make it the same like the others? required inputs with the same popup message >?

Comment: when using the required attribute, it makes the input element required.. I don't think you could use it on a group of checkbox fields.. though it would be nice.. so basically if you add 'required' to all your checkboxs, than ALL of them will be required and not only 1 of each..

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("input[name='gender[]']:checked").length > 0){

}
```

This should do the trick, not sure if it likes the [] in the name though.

Basicly tells jquery to fetch all the input's with the gender[] name who have been selected. All you have to do is check the length.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:checked` in jquery look this example [Jquery API documentation :checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

`var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;` with this you can check to know the number of inputs you want you would have to apply inputs according to the case you are validating, using a class selector in jquery.